# Finding intersection co-ordinate of two lines using four co-ordinates?

Tags: coordinates, intersection

I have a task in which I am trying to find out the intersection co-ordinates of two lines made with four co-ordinates.

I have tried using online tools like GeocachingToolbox however found the calculated intersection point is very in-accurate and it can be seen on the output to be not the actual intersection point.

Does anyone know how I can calculate this or is there a program I can use to make this calculation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking only for online solution? If, not you may consider using the QGIS or any other non-proprietary GIS Software or one of Python/R Geo-library.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the result depends on which Coordianate reference system (CRS) you use? Depending on the projection used, the intersection will be located in different places.

Comment: *Line-Line intersection* is rather trivial vector math - somewhat more complex for *segments* compared to infinite lines. Since I deem *JavaScript* to be easy to follow, try working through the gist of this implementation [here](https://github.com/pgkelley4/line-segments-intersect/blob/master/js/line-segments-intersect.js) - note that much of the actual function is ruling out several "special" cases (colinearity and equal points, parallelism and non-intersection of the segments). No need for full-grown GIS, really.